# Given column + rows of a terminal / tty, how to calculate min/max number of bytes that can fit

Tags: node.js, terminal, tty

Say we get the current columns and rows of a terminal with node.js:

```
console.log('rows:', process.stdout.rows);
console.log('columns:', process.stdout.columns);
```

is there a way to calculate the number of bytes that can fit in the terminal window? I mean I would guess that it's rows*columns, but I really have no idea.

My guess is that `rows*columns` is the *max* number of bytes that can fit, but in reality, it's probably less, it wouldn't be exact.

Comment: FYI bytes ≠ characters. The number of bytes here is irrelevant. You would be able to fit the same number of `Ω` characters as you would `O` characters, even though the number of bytes is different.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I want to know how many bytes to read from a file to display, it's sort of an optimization.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's right, that's why I am talking about max/min not exact, I think we can figure this out

Comment: For example, say we have  10 rows and 10 columns, so that's 100 characters max that can fit? That means that the *minimum* number of bytes that can be displayed is 100 also. Correct? Maybe there is no way to determine the maximum number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number depends on the nominal size of the window (rows times columns) as well as the way the character cells are *encoded*.  The node application assumes everything is encoded as UTF-8, so that means each cell could be 4 bytes (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533258/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-bytes-for-a-utf-8-encoded-character) for example).

Besides that, you have to allow for a newline at the end of each row (unless you're relying upon line-wrapping the whole time).  A newline is a single byte.

So...

(1 + *columns*) * *rows* * 4

as a first approximation.

If you take *combining characters* into account, that could increase the estimate, but (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438785/possible-combining-character-sequences-in-unicode)) the limit on **that** is not well defined.  In practice, those are rarely used in European characters, but are used in some Asian characters (*ymmv*).

Comment: this assumes that columns and rows represent the number of characters that can fit right? I think that's correct, but I am personally not sure